# If $R$ and $R'$ are isomorphic rings, when are $R/I$ and $R'/I'$ isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Here is the question I'm working on:

> Let $R$ and $R'$ be commutative rings, and let $I \subseteq R$, $I' \subseteq R'$ be ideals. If $f:R \rightarrow R'$ is a homomorphism with $f(I) \subseteq I'$, prove that $f_*:r+I \mapsto f(r) + I'$ is a well-defined homomorphism $f_*:R/I \rightarrow R'/I'$, which is an isomorphism if $f$ is.

The first part is fairly easy to show. The second part about the isomorphism actually seems to be false. Take this counterexample:

Let $R = \mathbb{Z}_{36}$, $R' = \mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_9$, with the isomorphism $f(a) = (a \mod 4, a \mod 9)$. Let $I$ be the ideal $\{0, 18\}$ in $R$, so that $f(I) = \{(0, 0), (2, 0)\}$. Let $I'$ be the ideal $\{(0, 0), (0, 3), (0, 6), (2, 0), (2, 3), (2, 6)\}$ in $R'$. Then all the conditions are satisfied, but $R/I$ has 18 elements while $R'/I'$ has 6, and the two are not isomorphic. I'm thinking that the second part is only true if you also specify that $I'$ actually is equal to $f(I)$. Is this a valid counterexample? Thanks for reading.

Comment: The condition $I'=f(I)$ is sufficient. Presumably the author intended that but forgot to specify it.

Comment: An easier counter-example is: Let $R$ be any non-trivial ring. Take $f=\operatorname{id}$, the identity of $R$, $I=\left\{0\right\}$, $I'=R$.